# Installing Microsoft Office 2010 in Ubuntu 17.10 with playonlinux does not proceed

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

When I tried to install an application with the help of playonlinux, an empty space came back after some time and the process didn't move forward.

Although my internet connection was very good I still waited for a long time, but the process did not make any progress and did not remove the blank space...

I'm using X.Org.

What can I do to solve this?

[image: screenshot while installing ms office]

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X.Org? Try starting an X session in the Ubuntu login screen.

Comment: yes I'm using x.org....and what is X session......there is no X session in the login screen... I found only GNOME Classic , Ubuntu & Ubuntu X.org in the login screen...

Comment: I meant X.Org when writing "X session", same thing.

Comment: But I'm using X.Org...so why the problem is created.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to fix. Just remove outdated libraries that ship with wine on playonlinux. In my case:

```
rm ~/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux-x86/1.7.52/lib/lib{z,gcrypt,jpeg}*
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please elaborate your answer adding explanations: How did you determine which files to remove?

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/home/prabin/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux-x86/1.7.52/lib/libjpeg*': No such file or directory                                                                        (how can I know what is in my case)

Comment: Okay. I found out which library was causing the problem (using debug output). It was automatically replaced with the one in path as soon as it was removed. I believe it was libz depending on FreeType. I've just also found it on Russian forum https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/13328075?lastmod=1491481798869#comment-13331989

Comment: In your case, search for the wine in .PlayOnLinux (I don't know the exact version you installed) and remove these libraries. I believe that helps as I've tested it on two different machines with different POL and Ubuntu versions installed. P. S. It looks like removing libjpeg is not necessary. The only thing you need to remove is libz*

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in xorg /wayland.

Found a workaround posted to bug #5562 by sheepex ([Fedora 26 : Wine cannot find the FreeType font library. (ABI issue??) | playonlinux.com](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/issue-5562.html))

```
rm ~/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux//lib/libz
```

[image]
<sup>**Before/After + PlayOnLinux, Office 2010, Ubuntu 17.10**</sup>

According to the Fedora form thread (linked in sheepex's comment), the issue is with playonlinux shipping with outdated lib32-zlib files.

Removing lib32-zlib fonts does not impact the activation process.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBeMI.png):

Comment: Does this Method allow to register on-line?

Comment: Registration is a topic worthy of a new thread, the post above only talks about installs.

Comment: To be a complete answer this should be included.